# Error in Delete function inside a vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have two required fields inside a `Visualforce Page`: `prodottoservizio`, `quant`. Inside the page I can build a list of objects shown inside a table. Now I want to insert a Delete Button that deletes all the object records created inside the controller extension and return to the previous URL.

Here my VF code:

```
 <apex:PageBlock id="contratto">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!createContr}" value="Scegli i Prodotti" reRender="panprodotti" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteContract}" value="Elimina Contratto e prodotti selezionati" onclick="window.history.back()" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Specifiche Contratto">
        <apex:input required="true" label="Data inizio contratto" value="{!cData}" type="date" id="datainiziocontr" />
        <apex:input required="true" label="Durata contratto(mesi)" value="{!cDurata}" type="number" id="durcontr" />
        <apex:input label="Condizioni speciali" value="{!cCondizioni}" type="text" id="condizioni" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
    apex:outputPanel id="panprodotti">
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!cData<>null}">
            <apex:pageBlock id="pselected">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Inserisci i Prodotti" collapsible="false" >
                    <apex:inputField required="true" id="prodottoservizio" value="{!prodotto.Scelta__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="gionol" value="{!prodotto.Giorni_durata_noleggio__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField required="true" id="quant" value="{!prodotto.Quantit_prodotto__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="sconto" value="{!prodotto.Sconto__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!addFromShoppingCart}" value="Aggiungi al Contratto" reRender="pinserted,panprodotti" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            </apex:pageBlock>
```

and this is my function:

```
public void deleteContract(){
    delete shoppingCart;
    delete nuovocontratto;
}
```

When I click the button I have an error because that two fields are required. How How can I solve this Problem?

P.S. I posted a code's portion because the controller is huge.

Comment: Seems like you included the wrong `commandButton` in your posted markup? It calls `addFromShoppingCart`, not `deleteContract`.

Comment: sorry, I post an old version, now I edit the post. Thank you for helping me

Comment: Use immediate =false

Comment: @SantanuBoral `false` is the default value for the `immediate` property...

Comment: Actually I meant to say true, but at time of writing wrongly written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass page-side validations by setting the `immediate="true"` property on a `commandButton` tag. In the case of a delete operation, it seems like that may be the appropriate course of action.

Here is the description of the `immediate` attribute in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm):

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the action associated with this component should happen immediately, without processing any validation rules associated with the fields on the page. If set to true, the action happens immediately and validation rules are skipped. If not specified, this value defaults to false.